# Not able to return values using provider factory in angular4

Tags: angular, angular-providers

I am new to angular and i want to populate some data before the component gets loaded, so i choose to use provider factory

**COMPONENT**

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { SaModelService, initConfiguration } from './sa-model.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: SaModelService,
      useFactory: () => (data: SaModelService) => {
        return data.load();
      }

    }
  ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private data: SaModelService) {

  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    alert(this.data)

  }

}
```

**SERVICE**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SaModelService {

  constructor() { }
  load() {
    return {
      name: 'foo',
      age: 10,
      contact: '720 890 1430'
    };
  }
}
export function initConfiguration(configService: SaModelService): Function {
  return () => configService.load();
}
```

now when i run this code, instead  of getting the value object which is getting returned from the function, i am getting the function, which is like this

[image]

how can i get the value instead of the function

Comment: where did you got that example from? You dont need to use a factory provider, just put SaModelService in the providers array at module level or component level.

Answer (score 0):

Dont really know what you want to achieve here. If the goal is to make sure you have initial data loaded before angular loads then this is how you do it:

In providers, use this instead:

```
{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER, // imported from @angular/core
    useFactory: requestInitialAppData, // Your function where you do stuff before angular loads 
    deps: [SaModelService] // Your service that will be injected to the function
    multi: true
},
```

Then adding a function where you handle the initial logic.

```
requestInitialAppData(SaModelService) {
   // Do your stuff here, and as I said, im not really sure what you ar trying to achieve here but this will give you a chance to populate data in services before angular loads.
}
```

Here is a guide that will help: [Angular 4 Tutorial - Run Code During App Initialization](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-4-tutorial-run-code-during-app-initialization/)